# Ciclos y switch lenjuage c (incognita)

Tags: c++, array, bucle-for, while

les traigo el siguiente codigo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream.h>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::cout;

int main()
{

    int entrada = 0, dinero[50], retencionactual[50],i=0,t=0,a=0;
    char regreso= 's';
    puts("\n");`
    puts("\t\t\t__________|BancoEsmeralda|_____________");
    puts("\n\nEscoga una operacion");
    printf("Deposito: %d" , "Variable" );
    puts("\n1.Deposito");
    puts("2.Retiro");
    puts("3.salir");
    puts("\nOpcion:");
    scanf("%d", &entrada);

    switch(entrada)
    {
        case 1:        
            for (i==0;i<50;++i){        
                printf("\nCuanto dinero desea ingresar:");
                scanf("%d", &dinero[i]);

                if (dinero[i]< 0 || dinero[i]==0)
                {
                    printf("\nLas cantidades no deben ser menores ni iguales a 0");
                }
                else
                {
                    retencionactual[i] = dinero[i];
                    t+=retencionactual[i];
                    printf("\nHas deposito%d",retencionactual[i]);
                    printf("\nDeposito total: %d",t);
                 }

                do{
                   printf("\nDesea realizar otro deposito? s/n:");
                   scanf("%s", &regreso);
                   if(regreso!='s')
                   {
                       return main();
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       continue;
                   }
            }
            while(regreso!='s');`
        }

   }
    break;
    case 2:

         printf("Esto es deposito");

         break;
    case 3:

     puts("Ha salido del programa");
     return 0;

    break;

}
```

El programa trata sobre un cuenta de banco, donde el usuario controlara la entrada y salida de dinero.

En el primer tenemos que el usuario va a ingresar n cantidad de transacciones, estas se van a ir acumulando en un contador, cada vez que el ingrese un numero el Do while le preguntara si quiere hacer otro deposito, si presiona s seguira y si no volvera al menu principal mostrando el valor total de transacciones.

El problema esta aquí, que no consigo como mantener el valor acumulado de la variable acumulada para lo mostrar al principio del `main` cuando el que quiere salir del case deposito.

Me he puesto a leer en algunos `pdfs`, y dice que  cada `case` es independiente del otro. Pero mi pregunta es: Siendo manejadas por variables globales no hay una posibilidad de que al volver el `main` se refleje la variable acumulado?, aun estando dentro del case y el ciclo `for`?

Con el `case` retiro tambien quería hacer algo parecido, pero no logro concretarlo todavía.

Que me recomiendan?.

Gracias ^^.

------ Actualizacion 30/19 -------

si Juan despues de leer un poco mas en otros foros, me di cuenta que lo que estaba haciendo estaba mal; la funcion (main) para regresar al menu no estaba funcionando como yo pense.

Por esa razon reestructure todo el codigo y quite switch, ya que no era la opcion adecuada.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream.h>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::cout;
int main()
{
int retiro,i=0,t=0,resto,o=0,separar[] = {};

    char regreso= 's';
    int long deposito;
    puts("\n");
    puts("\t\t\t__________|Banco Esmeralda|_____________");
    for (i==1;;++i)
    {
    printf("\nCuanto dinero desea ingresar:");
    scanf("%d", &deposito);
    if (deposito< 0 || deposito==0)
    {
        printf("\nLas cantidades no deben ser menores ni iguales a 0");
    }
    else
    if(deposito>50000)
    {
   // codigo.
    }
    t+=deposito;
    printf("\nHas deposito: %d",deposito);
    printf("\nDeposito total: %d",a);

        printf("\nDesea realizar otro deposito? s/n:");
        scanf("%s", &regreso);
        if(regreso!='s')
        {
         cout << "\nTotal depostitado:" << t;
         cout << "\nCantidad de deposito realizado" << "[" << ++i << "]";
         cout << "\nCantidad a partir de 50.000" << "[" << a << "]";
         break;
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
    for (i=0;;++i)
    {

        printf("\nDesea retirar? s/n:");
        scanf("%s", &regreso);
         if (regreso=='s')
        {
        puts("\nCuanto desea retirar:");
        scanf("%d",&retiro);
        t-=retiro;
        }
        if (t>0)
        {
            printf("actual en cuenta: %d",t);
        }
        else
        if(t<0)
        {
            printf("Sobrepasa la cantidad de deposito");
        }
}
}
```

Cabe destacar que todo esto es un ciclo infinito, aun me falta colocarle que salga completamente y cierre; He lograda que me calcule las cantidad y que el usuario pueda retirar la cantidad que desee. Repito aun no he puesto que haga sus otras funciones.

Ahora otro problema, en el ejercicio me dice que debo registrar todas las las cantidades mayores a 50000, osea que cuando el usuario ponga 600000 o otro mayor a la condicion le aparezca el numero contado y cuando haga otra y asi. Ejemplo:

```
printf("\nCuanto dinero desea ingresar:");
scanf("%d", &deposito);
y diga:

Cantidades mayores a 50.000 = 1;
Cantidades mayores a 50.000 = 2;
Cantidades mayores a 50.000 = 3; 
             .
             .
             .
```

LO que pensaba era meter las cantidad mayores en un arreglo y mostrarlas por medio de un contador o sino una variable global que valla contando las cantidades de veces que ingreso el usuario mayor al 500000. Pero no consigo como hacerlo :(.

Si pueden aconsejarme o ayudarme en esto, por favor :(.

Gracias!

Comment: Buenas tardes y gracias por contestar ^^

Answer (score 1):

Esto no hace lo que piensas.

```
return main();
```

Esto primero llama al método *main()* **otra vez**. Al llamar al método *main()*, crea una nueva copia independiente de todas las variables locales y empieza de nuevo la ejecución desde el principio.

Cuando acaba la ejecución del método (por ejemplo en el *return 0*) es cuando se ejecuta el *return* y sale de la invocación en la que estás.

Lo mejor será que elimines toda la parte del do-while para que veas como se acumulan los valores; más adelante ya complicarás el programa.

Comment: .............UP

Comment: compañero @SJuan76 el OP en su pregunta te va a dejar una actualización

Comment: Ya actualize, esta bien asi?